# UITableView: error after connected table view to datasource

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a simple TableView in my current project.
but I got this error after connected datasource in IB and run iOS simulator.

```
2013-03-22 14:58:32.372 M[1875:c07] -[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:      
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88191f0
2013-03-22 14:58:32.374 M[1875:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:        
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88191f0'
```

,but when I create a simple TableView in an empty project with the same code it's working.

Here is my code
"MCEventActivityViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MCEventActivityViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

"MCEventActivityViewController.m"

```
#import "MCEventActivityViewController.h"

@interface MCEventActivityViewController ()

@end

@implementation MCEventActivityViewController
{
    NSArray *tableData;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

@end
```

Could anyone help me figure out why this error came out?

The screenshots are here.
[image]

[image]

**Edited:**
[image]

Comment: problem is persist with the iboutlets of the table view and it's delegate, datasource connecting to filesowner. if possible take screen shot and add here for better suggestions!

Comment: OK. I already added the screenshots.

Comment: please put this method - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView and return 1; inside the method @strc

Comment: have you connected your table view outlet with file owner ?

Comment: yes, I already did it.

Comment: from your screenshot seems, you are checking UIView outlet not the UITableView outlet.Create, @property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITabelView * tableView;and connect this Outlet in Xib with Fileowner

Comment: Thanks Vedchi, I've followed your suggestion and the error isn't gone.
Could you please check my new screenshot that is correct or not.

Comment: running in iOS 5.x or iOS 6.x ? If you are running in iOS 5.x then uncheck the Use Autolayout for you XIB.

Comment: I'm running it in iOS 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure,

1.TableView is connected with FileOwner in XIB.

2.@interface Controller : UIViewController UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource  included.

3.`Delegate` & `DataSource` both connected  with FileOwner.

4.`numberOfSections` return 1.

5.`numberOfRowsInSection` returns [required].

6.`cellForRowAtIndexPath` 
{ data goes here...
}

Edited:

Create,
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITabelView * tableView;

and connect this Outlet in Xib with Fileowner

Answer (score 0):

Add `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method to your code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Add `NSArray *tableData;` to `MCEventActivityViewController.h`

and set its `@property` and `@synthesize` properly.

and write

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still got the same error after added this code.

Comment: hi friends...numberOfSectionsInTableView: delegate method by default will return 1. and it is an optional delegate method see the UITableViewDelegate methods once.

Comment: Thanks iPatel for your help, but the error isn't went away.

I wonder why my blank/new project is working, but for my current project isn't working with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You should link the (**dataSource and delegate**) from Outlets to the **view controller** not to view ! like these pictures :

[image]

[image]

[image]